# It is correct to say "All who believe" or All who believes?"

Tags: verbs, subjects, agreement

Is "All" the subject in this sentence or is "who" the subject?
If all is the subject then believe would be the correct verb agreement.
If who is the subject then believes would be the correct verb agreement.
So which is the subject please?

Comment: _All_ modifying or substituting for a count noun (like _people_, as here) is always plural, so _who_, which refers to the same thing, is also plural, and therefore the verb is plural _believe_, not singular _believes_.

Comment: That's not a sentence, it's a [noun phrase](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/noun-phrase) consisting of a pronoun with a [restrictive clause](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/restrictive_clause.htm).

Comment: *Who* is not always singular, that is, it's not always third person singular.

Answer (score 3):

*All who believe* is not a sentence; it's a noun phrase.

Taking a sentence starting with *all who believe* we get

> All who believe are believers.

The correct verb form is *believe*.

*Who* is not bound to third person singular verb form.

> The people who believe are believers.

*Who* takes the verb form of the subject *the people*.

> Neighbors who insist on believing  are believers.

*Who insist on believing* is the relative clause. But *who* is plural in this case because its antecedent is the plural subject *neighbors*.

The same concept goes for

> Who am I?

*Who* is not third person singular. Its verb agrees with the subject it's standing for.

> I who believe am a believer.

*Who* stands for *I*, which takes *am*.

As another example showing *who* is not always third person singular is

> You people who are here believe.

*Who* takes the verb that agrees with *you people* (second person plural).

Also, second person singular:

> Who are you?

and

> You, who are my best friend, are a believer.

---

Finally,   you can also say

> All that believe are believers.

That substitution should be a hint that the relative pronoun can be either either singular or plural.